# How to mock this class

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking

```
class A
{
public:
    void doFirstJob() 
    {
        // Do first Job.
    }
}

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void doSecondJob()
    {
        // Do Second Job.
    }
}

class C
{
public:
    void doSomething() {
        b->doFirstJob();
        b->doSecondJob();
    }
private:
    B* b;
}
```

Now I should write unit test code for class C, then I'll write a mock for class B, but the problem is how to mock the method **doFirstJob().**

Bluntly, I want know how to mock the non-virtual method of the parent class???

Can any one help me ??

Comment: Why is doSecondJob virtual if the class is not being inherited by anything?

Comment: Usually, a mock class is implemented, and unit tests ran linking this last class insted of the "real" one.

Answer (score 1):

[Typemock Isolator++](https://www.typemock.com/isolatorpp-product-page) supports mocking non virtual methods of a parent class (same as faking a method of the class under test).

See following example:

```
class A
{
public:
    int doFirstJob() 
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

class B : public A
{

};

class C
{
public:

    int doSomething() 
    {
        return b->doFirstJob();
    }
    void setB(B* to)
    {
        b = to;
    }
private:
    B* b;
};
```

In the test You create a fake of B -> change the behavior of doFirstJob to return 3 -> continue with your test as you would normally write it.

```
TEST_CLASS(NonVirtualMethod)
{
public:

    TEST_METHOD(NonVirtualMethodTestOfBaseClass)
    {
        B* fakeB = FAKE<B>(); 
        WHEN_CALLED(fakeB->doFirstJob()).Return(3);

        C c;
        c.setB(fakeB);
        int first = c.doSomething();

        Assert::AreEqual(3,first);
    }
}
```

You can find more examples [here](https://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Ipp&page=Documentation%2Fhow_do_i_fake___.htm).